# Xcode debug expressions incorrect

Tags: xcode

I'm using XCode 4.2.  When I set a breakpoint and check the values of my variables (whether they be Auto, local, or expressions I enter myself) the values return with "empty" type values (integers = 0, BOOL=false, etc.  The structure of my objects are correct, but the values don't display the correct information.

Watching the program execution flow confirms that the variables have a value other than the "empty" one since loops and conditional work correctly based on what the variables SHOULD contain.

I am assuming that my debug symbols are not being created correctly (or are corrupt), but I am not sure how to set that in XCode.

I have tried:

- I have confirmed that my schema is debug.
- I have changed my debugger to GDB

Can anyone help me out?